# How to audit MFA status of users in Azure

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, azure-policy, policies

I am trying to build a Policy definition to list out the users who have not enabled MFA in Azure.
I saw that i can't target users through Policy

Any solutions or views?

I tried altering the built-in policy which requires users to have MFA enabled mandatory but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I dont think Azure Policy can do this. you can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authenticationmethodsroot-list-userregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http this rest api to list MFA details.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Policy does not do anything meaningful for Entra ID (which used to be Azure AD) users, at least from what I know. I think what you might be looking for is a Conditional Access policy, that can certainly require users to use MFA. Depending on your needs you may also do better with Security Defaults, which enable some basic Microsoft recommendations. Some references below.

Conditional Access: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/conditional-access/overview

Security Defaults: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/security-defaults

As far as audit, its been a while since I looked at this problem myself, but this seems like a recent enough source: https://www.alitajran.com/get-mfa-status-entra/